# Get this week users

Tags: get, this, dayofweek

I have this code:

```
$sdf = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (DATE(date) = date_sub(date('2013-11-02 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
```

And would like to get this week's users.. how many who have created an account this week. Now it add's one week from today to next monday. BUT. I want JUST this week, not 7 days forward. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `date_format` is enough for what you need.

```
select *
from users
where DATE_FORMAT(your_date_column,"%u-%Y") = "44-2013"
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: 44 is the week number of your date. Do you prefer 42 ? :) In a year, you've got 52/53 weeks.

Comment: Great. :) 42 is always a great help.